# Proving two Binomial Coefficient summations are equal.

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

$$\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\binom{k+n}{2n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\binom{2k-n-1}{n}$$

I understand at least on a case by case that these are summing the odd diagonals of pascals triangle, but in opposite directions, but my binomial identities are lacking.

Comment: Did you try induction?

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\binom{k+n}{2n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\binom{k+(k-1-n)}{2(k-1-n)+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\binom{2k-n-1}{2k-2n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\binom{2k-n-1}{n}$$

The first equality is based on: $$\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}a_n=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}a_{k-1-n}$$

The third equality is based on: $$\binom{m}{n}=\binom{m}{m-n}$$